# C++: Why pass lambda to unordered_map empty constructor?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Lets say I want to define an `unordered_map` with `pair<int,int>` as key.
We can define the hash function as a function object (which means, overload the `operator()(const pair<int,int>& arg)`), or define it as a lambda.

Why we need to pass the lambda in the constructor?
Why we have to write `unordered_map<pair<int,int>, int, decltype(lambda)> var {0, lambda}`, rather than `unordered_map<pair<int,int>, int, decltype(lambda)> var {0}`? Isn't lambda has its default value?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda . Note the "`ClosureType() = default;`   (since C++20)(only if no captures are specified)". In short, the closure type has no default constructor until C++20

Comment: The code should not compile until c++20 as you can try yourself.